# Changing the elements of numpy.ndarray of Keras ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, keras, data-generation, data-augmentation

I am using Keras ImageDataGenerator for data augmentation. 
After generating ImDatagenerator as follows,

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator( rescale=1./255.)     
DG = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        directory='Path_To_Dataset',
        target_size=(img_rows, img_cols), color_mode='rgb',
        classes=['c1', 'c2'], 
        class_mode='categorical',
        batch_size=32, shuffle=True, seed=42,
        subset=None, interpolation='bicubic'
        )
```

I am trying to change one image's pixels of `DG` by simply assigning a numpy.ndarray with the same size as follows

```
DG[0][0][0,:,:,:] = np.random.rand(img_rows,img_cols,3)
```

While **it does not give any error, but I do not observe any change** in the DG.

Comment: Do you want to do this change to all the images in the batch, or is it just for a one image in the batch?

Comment: I want to apply some changes to all images, for example, suppose I wanna apply multiple filters over all images (not necessarily all images within a patch receive same change)